# Object[] inside Object[] Java returns memory address?

Tags: java, arrays, object

Trying to access any `Object[]` inside the initial `Object[]` returns the memory address i.e. `System.out.println(Object[1]);`.

How do I get it to return its contents instead?

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Object[1]));`?

Comment: it is not memory address, it is its hashcode for numeric part, check toString()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `System.out.println` on an array (or any other object for that matter), you implicitly invoke its `toString()` method (assuming it's not `null`, of course). Arrays implement it in a trivial manner, so, as you mentioned, you get the address, which is not very useful.

[`Arrays.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(boolean[])) should give you more useful output:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Objects[1]));
```

Or better yet, you could use [`Arrays.deepToString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object[])) to print the entire "parent" array:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(Objects));
```

Comment: It works, however I had to specify the array was an object. System.out.println(Arrays.toString((Object[]) objects[1])); returns the contents. How would I access a certain item in the array within the array?

Answer (score 0):

Simple do this

```
outerObj = Object[1];
System.out.println(outerObj[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are putting a String inside your object then you can do this:

```
System.out.println(((String)Object[1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Java prints that rubbish when invoking toString() on an array.
To print an array legibly:

```
Arrays.toString( array );
```

But you have an array of arrays, so the nested arrays still get the toString() treatment.
But! There's a way out!

```
Arrays.deepToString( arrayOfArrays);
```